# Unable to mount a DVD on HP-UX 11

Tags: dvd, mount, compact-disc, hp-ux

I'm trying mount a DVD (or a CD) on HP-UX 11.31, like so:

```
$ mount -F cdfs -o rr /dev/dsk/c0t2d0 /dvdrom
/dev/dsk/c0t2d0: unrecognized file system
```

I've tried each other devices listed in `/dev/dsk/` with the same result.

I've also tried `mount -F cdfs -o cdcase`. Same problem.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

12 years back... A little late with my opinion about mounting cdrom/dvd:
requirementes:
A.-Security in a multiuser environment (Any Operating System obvious in my opinion)

- The existence of the physical (virtual or emulated) device, being it well conected and recognized by firmware/bios/ISL/kernel/virtio/drivers...
- The existence of the mount point (it doesn't implies you can use it).
- Access granted for the unit/volume/folder where the mount point (folder name) is located (test it copying one text file to the unit and remove it inmediately) (r/w access doesn't implies you have rights to mount the device)
- Access granted for mounting the device (Only one mounted device per mount point, the second instance is usaully rejected)

workaorund: as granted access user for the OS/machine and the mount command, you should can create your own mount point in your home folder:

```
$ mkdir /cdrom001; /sbin/mount -F cdfs /dev/dsk/c0t2d0 /cdrom001
mount: must be root to use mount

# mkdir /cdrom001; mount -F cdfs /dev/dsk/c0t2d0 /cdrom001
```

NOTES:
/cdrom001 implies that you have access to root (/) filesystem
mkdir /cdrom001 correct execution of this command tell us you have granted permision for the root filesystem

A.-Technical

HP-UX v 10.2 (and many flavours of UNIX SVR4 or BSD) command:
Requirements :
a.- For the media CD or DVD
format: ISO9660   style: Rock Ride   (only)
Not suitable for JOLIET, UDF, etc.
Rock Ride for composition of the +8,1 characters in filenames
b.- Compatible unit media reader

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this information from the Unix [man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mount+8) page and my own Linux system. I don't know anything about hp-ux so hopefully this applies.

When I do a `ls -al /dev` on my linux system, I get various devices named dvd, cdrom, and scd0 which are all symbolic links to sr0. You might have something similar.

I am able to mount cdrom's with a line like this:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /cdrom
```

where /cdrom is a pre-created directory for mounting cds. You might have some directories under /mnt that you can use. I can replace /dev/cdrom with /dev/dvd or /dev/sr0... it all goes to the same place.

Mount is usually smart enough to figure out what file-system type it is trying to mount so you can usually get away with a line like this:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom
```

Where you only need to specify the device you'd like to mount and the location or directory you'd like to mount it to.

These command would need to be run as root. If you have an entry in /etc/fstab or /etc/mmtab for the cdrom... then you can mount it with something like

```
mount /dev/cdrom
```

where the mount point is predefined. Here is a snippet from the Unix man page:

```
   The file /etc/fstab (see fstab(5)), may contain lines  describing  what
   devices  are  usually  mounted where, using which options. This file is
   used in three ways:

   (i) The command
      mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]
   (usually given in a bootscript) causes all file  systems  mentioned  in
   fstab  (of  the  proper  type  and/or  having  or not having the proper
   options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose  line  con-
   tains the noauto keyword. Adding the -F option will make mount fork, so
   that the filesystems are mounted simultaneously.

   (ii) When mounting a file system mentioned in  fstab,  it  suffices  to
   give only the device, or only the mount point.

   (iii)  Normally,  only  the superuser can mount file systems.  However,
   when fstab contains the user option on a line, anybody  can  mount  the
   corresponding system.

   Thus, given a line
      /dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide
   any user can mount the iso9660 file system found on his CDROM using the
   command
      mount /dev/cdrom
   or
      mount /cd
```